# Overstayed as a minor. Will I get the ESTA approval?

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program, overstaying, minors

I moved to the US when I was 5 and moved back to my home country at the age of 13. Its been 13 years since then. I want to travel to the US for a short holiday and was wondering if I would get denied the ESTA for the Visa Waiver. Specially since I have to answer "yes" to the "8) Have you ever stayed in the United States longer than the admission period granted to you by the U.S. government?" question. I know that overstaying as a minor doesn't really count for ban purposes, but I'm not sure what will happen when I apply.

Any insights? Thanks :)